# About convert dbc to xlsx & xlsx to dbc using canmatrix package

Tags: xlsx, converters, can-bus

I am trying to convert dbc files to xlsx for editing, after that I want to convert the xlsx back to dbc file.

I download the [canmatrix](https://github.com/ebroecker/canmatrix) package and install that with python3.8. I like to explain what I did then ask questions.

1, I load the dbc file in my python fold and created an xlsx file as the target file.

2, Using code `canconvert source.dbc target.xlsx`. This gives me a good output for all dbc signals, messages, and value tables.

3, After some testing change, I convert the xlsx back to dbc, using `canconvert target.xlsx source1.dbc`.

4, I run the comparing code as `cancompare source.dbc source1.dbc`.

The conversion is great and fast. However, there are many things that I did not change and have many changes I do not like to see.

Questions:

1, Every time I run the converted code, it shows "ldf is not supported" & "yaml is not support". What are those? Should I worry about them and fix them?

2, convert code give me the xlsx without many values, such as min and max values. This gives me a lot of difference when I run the compare code.

For example, I have a signal set as -5 as min before. The new one gives me 0 min.
3, Many unused signals, messages, and valuetable have been deleted. This is not what I want. I do not like the conversion deleted those unused items because I may use them somewhere or someplace later. Therefore, Is there any way that code will not delete?

*I also install the xlrd1.2 xlwt1.3 as the code requires that.*

Please let me know if you have any idea or some link that may help me somehow.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problems too, "ldf is not supported" & "yaml is not support" means you miss these two python packages, you can download "yaml" with command "pip install pyyaml", but the "ldf" issue, I have no idea.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your info. I have installed the package using 'pip install pyyaml'. I think I got the package for ldf too. I am not sure but try 'pip install ldfparser'. After 2 packages are installed. No error found so far. However, the xlsx outpt still not what I want. I mean there are a lot attibute are not included.